# How do I import configurable products with attributes (color,size), attribute sets, categories and images with magmi?

Tags: magento, csv, magmi, configurable

**How do I import configurable products with attributes (color,size), attribute sets, categories and images with magmi?**

If someone can provide a CSV file with a format that actually works that I could use to import products I would be more than happy to write a blog post to include the details for every poor soul that finds this awesome tool dubbed 'magmi.'  I have searched quite a bit and cannot find working csv sample files that do what I need.

Here is some sample data below:

"SKU","Description","Size","Color","Image","in-stock","quantity","visibility","type"

"1480RSMALL","This is style 1480 in color red, size small.","Small","Red","1480rsmall.jpg","Yes",150,"Not Visibile Individually","Simple Product"

"1480GLARGE","This is style 1480 in color green, size large.","Large","Green","1480glarge.jpg","Yes",54,"Not Visibile Individually","Simple Product"

"1480YMEDIUM","This is style 1480 in color yellow, size medium.","Medium","Yellow","1480ymedium.jpg","Yes",8,"Not Visibile Individually","Simple Product"

"1480","This is style 1480 available in multiple colors and sizes.","","","1480.jpg","Yes",,"Catalog, Search","Configurable Product"

Also, does magmi work with newer column names that have "_" on the front?

Answer (score 0):

Just export your product from your site..If you have no product then install magento in your local server with magento sample data from [Magento](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ce18-and-ee113-installing#install-sample)

The sample data contains all kind products with itself. So you can get your csv format now..

Answer (score 0):

Magmi handles LEGACY  (1.4) dataflow format with no underscores, **NOT IMPORT/EXPORT** format with one line per multivalued attribute of the same product.

Then required columns varies depending on what you want to do :

- Create new items require more data
- updating existing require only sku & the columns corresponding to the attributes to change

For creating configurables, you'll need standard mandatory attributes column (no underscore) as well as "configurable_attributes" column, telling magmi which are the pivot fields to use.

Magmi Wiki has some sample (but not complete files)

A thing to understand is that magmi can adapt lot of things with the good plugins, so there is no single "standard" input format. But the base compatibility format is Dataflow format with no underscores. THen depending on what you want to do, some specific extensions of the format have been defined, all documented in plugin documentation (links in the UI)